# How to save an excel file as pdf through Matlab on Mac?

Tags: excel, macos, matlab, pdf

I am a Mac user, I want to use matlab to write data in excel and then I want to save the excel file as PDF file format. I was able to do this on Windows using actxserver, but unfortunately this option doesn't work for Mac. 
Does anyone have a solution for saving an excel file as PDF file format through Matlab on Mac?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question really is, "How can I automatically generate pdf files from Excel files on Mac OS X?" If there's code, in any language, that allows you to do this nicely, you can always call "system" command from MATLAB to execute the external program.

Comment: To get really robust PDF output, you may have to do something semi-crazy like have a virtual machine running windows and do the actual pdf generation there (I've heard of people doing this before, but it doesn't sound pleasant.)

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean but it sounds like a turn around. I was wondering if I call system command works for that, but I have no idea what should be the command like: It should look maybe something like that "system(['SaveAsFixedFormat filename.xlsx']), but unfortunately I am not finding the right command to write in there